# wirte on external sd card does not work

Tags: android

My app doesn't seem to have writing permissions on my external sd card. I can read from it, but writing does only work on the internal one (sdcard0).
When i try

```
File f = new File("/storacge/sdcard1/Test/file.mp3");
boolean b = f.delete();
```

then b is `false` and the file still exists. But i can play it with `MediaPlayer`.

I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in my Manifest

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1)You need to ask for runtime permissions

2)Don't assume that the path is /storage/sdcard1.  That varies between devices.  Request the name via getExternalFilesDirs

Comment: the app is only for me and my device, where i have android 5 and therefore no runtime permissions and in the final version the path won't be hard coded anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on Android 6.0 or higher you will have to request for permissions exactly where you need them.

Create a method in your activity as such:

```
public void askForWritePermissions(){
    //If android marshmellow or higher
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        //If permissions are not granted
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},2);

        }
    }
}
```

And call the above method on whichever event you need. After the user grants access or doesn't grant access to the permissions, onRequestPermissionsResult() is called so make sure you handle that method appropriately.

Comment: i have a new phone now, modiefied the path and iserted the permission request. Still the same result

Comment: Post log cat here